# Android Youtube Auth Sign In SDK

Tags: android, authentication, youtube, youtube-api, google-signin

Following the guide 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in
doesn't allow me to specify the channel for youtube sign in

I requested the following scopes

```
    new Scope("email"),
new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"),
new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly")
```

Then

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL), scopes)
                .requestServerAuthCode(activity.getString(R.string.google_token_id), true)
                .build();
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .enableAutoManage(activity, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
```

While what i would like to implement a sign in like youtube does...

Where you can choose the channel you would like to connect.

I know that using a webView and OAuth 2.0 i can select the channel but i would like to do it with Android sdk for auth like youtube does...

Thank you for any insight

[image]

Comment: di you find any solution other than using a webView?

Comment: There is none...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The channel selector is unfortunately not available in the Android native sign-in flow. Using the native flow and the 'youtube' auth scope will yield a token for the account's "default channel": https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6019090?hl=en

To access the channel selector, you'll need to use the web-based flow as you mentioned.

Comment: Any idea if the SDK is updated and nor provides the channel selector for the proper scopes set?